# typescript function returning object whose each value is same as the key

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm defining a function that returns an object whose each value is same as the key to overcome [some limitation in Typescript enum](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38806) like

```
type OverrideValue<K> = {
  [P in keyof K]: P
}

const createEnum = <T>(obj: T) => {
  return (Object.keys(obj) as unknown as (keyof T)[]).reduce<OverrideValue<T>>((prev, curr) => prev[curr] = curr, {});
};
```

which complains:

```
Type 'keyof T' is not assignable to type 'OverrideValue<T>'.
  Type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to type 'OverrideValue<T>'.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'OverrideValue<T>'.ts(2322)
```

Somehow below ugly replacement has no problem.

```
createEnum = <T>(obj: T) => {
  let result = {} as OverrideValue<T>;
  
  (Object.keys(obj) as unknown as (keyof T)[]).forEach(key => {
    result[key] = key;
  });
  
  return result;
};
```

Is there any way that I can make it with `reduce`?

#### Solution

@jcalz pointed out that I wasn't aware of what my callback was returning.

```
const createEnum = <T>(obj: T) => {
  return (Object.keys(obj) as unknown as (keyof T)[]).reduce((prev, curr) => {
    prev[curr] = curr;
    return prev;
  }, {} as OverrideValue<T>);
};
```

Comment: `reduce()` expects the callback to return the accumulator; in your case, you are returning `prev[curr] = curr` which is essentially just `curr`.  You can fix it like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NBk74m), using the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) to choose what to return.  Not sure why you *want* to use `reduce()` for this, since reduce is not designed for mutating a single object, but that would at least fix it. I could write that up as an answer post if it meets your needs; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `[keyof T]` instead of, e.g., `Array<keyof T>` / `(keyof T)[]`?  `[keyof T]` is a one-element tuple and doesn't really apply to `Object.keys(obj)`, although the `reduce()`/`forEach()` methods of a tuple and an array are the same.  Unless your question is about tuples, you should probably [edit] the code to use `Array<keyof T>` so as not distract from your actual issue.

Comment: @jcalz thank you so much, would you please write them as an answer? I corrected `[key of T]` as you said, not to mislead future readers. I made a lot of mistakes in this as I've been away from TS for some time...